# New to Lua, confused by error <eof>

Tags: lua, eof, minecraft

I recently started taking an interest in Lua programming with a Minecraft addon called Computercraft, which involves console-based GUIs to control computers and other things with Lua.  However, I seem to be randomly getting an error where the code requires something called an "eof".  I have searched multiple manuals and how-tos, and none mention this particular error.  In fact, I am having trouble finding anything with an error list.  I am fairly new to programming, but have had basic Python experience.  Could anyone explain what "eof" is?

Comment: I know nothing about Lua, but "eof" generally means "end of file". It might be that this error is indicating you have reached the end of your file but Lua was expecting something more -- the end of a functional block for example. Again, I know nothing about Lua so take my comment to be worth what you paid for it.

Comment: If Lua requests the eof (end of file) that means that there should be the end of the file but instead there is more code. That happens if you put an `end` too much in your code. If you could post the Lua code and the exact error message we might be able to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 2):

An `eof` is `do` or `then`.

Usually `eof` means you have too many (or not enough) `end` statements. Paste code maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I create a file with one too many `end` statements:

`> edit test.lua`

```
for i = 1, 10 do
  print(i)
end
end
```

When I run it, and `lua` encounters that extra `end` statement on the last line where there is no code block still open, you'll get an error like:

`> test.lua`

```
bios: 337: [string "test.lua"]: 4: '<eof>' expected
```

(from a quick test in [CCDesk pr7.1.1](http://ccdesk.afterlifelochie.net/))

Problems with the basic structure of the blocks of lua code show up with `bios` on the left rather than your file name; the part of `bios` that loads lua files will usually tell you where it was at in the file when couldn't make sense of the code anymore (like line `4:` here).  Sometimes it might be a bit of a puzzle to work your way from the scene of the accident back to where things got off track. =)

Answer (score 0):

Using ESPlorer there is a difference between "uploading" a script and "sending" a script. Use "Upload".

This is not the same issue as the one reported, but as searching landed me here...